# Copy NSView in cocoa / objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I can't see any way to copy an NSView and create an identical NSView object.  I see google hits about "use an NSData" but I don't understand that.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To straight up "copy" an NSView, the view has to implement the `NSCopying` protocol.  Unfortunately, NSView does not.

Fortunately, it *does* implement the `NSCoding` protocol, which means we can still duplicate a view like:

```
NSData * archivedView = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myView];
NSView * myViewCopy = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archivedView];
```

And voilá!  You now have a duplicate of `myView`.

---

Edit: (Swift version)

```
let archivedView = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myView)
let myViewCopy = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedView)
```

(`archivedView` is of type `Data`, not `NSData`)

Comment: Note that if you subclass, you'll need to implement archiving support.   The docs know all.

Comment: In every case that I subclass - even when I don't have data added but only a couple methods?

Comment: Nektarios: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmImplementCopy.html

Comment: Lifesaver. I waded through a few results in Google and confusion until I found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Unarchiving doesn't work for me when using an NSTextField. It throws the error `"This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'NSTextField' does not adopt it."`. I can't for the life of me figure our a way around this.

Comment: I found a solution! See my answer to this question.

Answer (score 5):

Since around iOS 12 / macOS 14, the accepted answer by `@Dave DeLong` doesn't work anymore in all cases.

The problem is, that some of the methods which were used in `@Dave DeLong`s solution **don't work anymore** for objects that **only** adhere to the `NSCoding` protocol but **not** the `NSSecureCoding` protocol.

---

**Solution**

Luckily, there's still a solution that works for copying **any** Object that adheres to `NSCoding` (and not only ones that adhere to `NSSecureCoding`) even on the newest operating systems!

There are a few changes in this solution compared to the old one. Most importantly, you'll have to create an instance of `NSKeyedUnarchiver` instead of using the more convenient class methods. The convenient class methods only support `NSSecureCoding` but not `NSCoding` in the newer operating systems.

My implementation looks like this:

```
public func insecureCopy<T: NSCoding>(of original: T) throws -> T {
    
    /// See https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107533
    
    if #available(macOS 10.13, *) {
    
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: original, requiringSecureCoding: false)
        
        let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)
        unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = false
        
        let copy = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! T
        
        return copy
        
    } else { /// Fallback (untested)
        
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: original)
        
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
        unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = false
        
        let copy = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! T
        
        return copy
        
    }
}
```

---

**Notes**

- The source for this solution was from `@eskimo`s great answer on this Apple Dev Forum Post: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/107533

  as well as the WWDC session video that they linked to.
- The method is called `insecureCopy()` because it works on non-secure coding objects. But, as far as I understand, this method is not in fact insecure. Working with non-secure NSCoding objects is only insecure if you save and load insecure archives to and from a file as far as I understand. Not if you just use the archives for copying like in this case.
- The fallback code for macOS 10.13 and earlier is not tested.