# Adding a copy of an NSTabViewItem from an NSTabView into the same NSTabView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, nstabview

I'm creating a simple web browser and would like to implement tabs. For this purpose, I'm using an `NSTabView`. I basically want each tab to have a `WebView` that will show the website loaded. I'm starting with only one tab and want to add an exact copy of the first one when I create a new tab. I tried something like `tabView.addTabViewItem(tabView.tabViewItemAtIndex(0).copy() as NSTableViewItem)` but I'm getting an `unrecognised selector sent to instance` error. I've check the documentation for both `NSTableView` and `NSTableViewItem` but can't figure out how to that.

**EDIT**
My whole error looks like this:

```
015-03-14 17:15:57.884 Browser[1955:56547] -[NSTabViewItem copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000100b40
2015-03-14 17:15:57.884 Browser[1955:56547] -[NSTabViewItem copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600000100b40
```

Comment: could you post more of your code?  specifically where tabView is initialized.  Also if you could paste more of the stack in your error, that will help too ^^

Comment: @MattyAyOh I don't really have code initialising the tabView since it's done with the Cocoa builder, I've posted the whole error to the question, hope it helps.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/rsms/chromium-tabs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the answer on [Copy NSView in cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107429/copy-nsview-in-cocoa-objective-c) and @MattyAyOh, I solved my problem by doing:

```
var data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(view)
var newView = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as NSView
newTab.view = newView
tabView.addTabViewItem(newTab)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting that error because you are calling `copy()` on an object that doesn't have `-copyWithZone` implemented.  (Because NSTabViewItem subclasses NSView which doesn't conform to the `NSCopying` protocol)

What you can do to get around that is to initialize a new `NSTabViewItem`, then get the properties from the first item (`tabViewItemAtIndex(0)`), and then set them to your new `NSTabViewItem`

from the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTabViewItem_Class/)

you can call `setLabel`, `setIdentifier`, `setColor`, `setView`, and `setTooltip`

Once you've initialized and set your new `NSTabViewItem`, you can then add it to your `NSTabView`

```
NSTabViewItem *tempTabViewItem = [NSTabViewItem new];
//set your properties on tempTabViewItem here
tabView.addTabViewItem(tempTabViewItem);
```

Comment: Seems like a good idea except that it doesn't do the same effect as copying the tab using `copy`, by setting the view using `setView()`, the view points to the same object, so the WebViews can't load two different web pages.