# Using Xcode and Interface Builder to create prototype views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm building an NSView that is a kind of collection view, but instead of a table or a grid it will be a graph editor (similar to quartz composer).

The problem I'm facing now is that I would like to load prototype views (for the nodes) from a `xib` file. Much like how UITableView and UICollectionView lets you design prototype cells in Interface Builder. But how are these objects then instantiated in multiple copies?

How does UITableViewController et. al. achieve this?

Solutions I have thought about:

- Copy the view, but `NSView` does not support `NSCopying` "out of the box". This seems like the most logical so far. It also seems like the only option if you want to keep the NSView in a `storyboard` rather than a `xib`.
- Load a nib and then send `[nib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:nil]` multiple times.
- `NSView` does support `NSCoding` but using that feels more like a hack.

Any more ideas?

I'm developing an Mac OS X app, not an iOS app.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct, implementing `NSCopying` via `NSCoding` *does* feel like a hack, but it's prob'ly the quickest and most reliable way to code it.

[Copy NSView in cocoa / objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107429/copy-nsview-in-cocoa-objective-c) "related copy/code answer"

You can put your view in the storyboard as a top level object of any given scene. Make sure you have an outlet to it from the controller/loader of that scene. You could likely pack it into an NSData and just hold on to that for each "copy" you want made/unarchived.

Comment: Really? You think this is better than "Load a nib and then send `[nib instantiateNibWithOwner:self topLevelObjects:nil]` multiple times"? I mean, that's what a nib _is_: a way of instantiating a whole bunch of views together as many times as you like. And it's better to go thru all the trouble of making the view hierarchy copyable?

Comment: I _do_ prefer your `nib?.instantiate(withOwner: self, topLevelObjects: nil)` (to arbitrarily translate it to Swift) model. I'm uncertain of the actual implementation details. If the file involved is not cached, this option could be considerably slower. Whereas saving your prototype in a `Data` object is guaranteed to be in memory.  Realistically, i doubt the runtime hit would be noticeable.  (I would qualify this as _equally quick and likely as reliable_.)

Comment: I might also use _nib?.instantiate(withOwner: **nil**, topLevelObjects: **objects**)_ and pass in a mutable array to return the view, not requiring an owner or an outlet within that owner to get a reference to the newly instantiated view.

Comment: "I'm uncertain of the actual implementation details" All the more reason not to say copying is better. You recommend archiving and copying, and you worry that instantiating a nib might be heavyweight???